# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to get Intent data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have made an application where an activity is browsable. I followed the same code as [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

In Android code I can easily can get the URL from where it was redirected.

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String scheme = data.getScheme(); // "http"
String host = data.getHost(); // "twitter.com"
List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
String first = params.get(0); // "status"
String second = params.get(1); // "1234"
```

How can I get this Intent data to JavaScript? Is there an easy way?
I am working with Worklight 6.1, that works with Cordova 3.1.

Comment: Well, you could do that with either a Cordova plug-in or using WL.NativePage.show, probably.

Answer (score 2):

I think this training module will be beneficial:

- [Android – Adding native functionality to hybrid application with Apache Cordova plugin](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_05_Android_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf)
- [Sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/AndroidApacheCordovaPluginProject.zip)

The training module, and sample, show how to transfer data from Hybrid to Native and back.